# MongoDB on the native driver port

Tags: mongodb

> You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number

Este es el mensaje que me sale cuando intento acceder a http://localhost:27017/ luego de tener a `mongo` corriendo.

¿A qué se refiere con la siguiente frase?

> ... For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number

Tengo mi aplicación por el puerto 3000, y sin ningun problema, lo quiero saber es que significa este mensaje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No uso *Mongo*, pero el mensaje te está diciendo, mas o menos, que estás intentando conectarte **mediante *HTTP*** al puerto de conexión utilizado para el **protocolo nativo** (que, aparentemente, **no es** *HTTP*).

> ... For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number

Te dice que, para propósitos de depuración **de *Mongo***, te conectes mediante *HTTP* al puerto `1000` + **el que estás usando**, es decir, que te conectes a

> http://localhost:28017

Todo lo anterior es siempre referente a *Mongo*; no tiene nada que ver con tu aplicación.

Comment: Ahhhhh. no pense en eso, no es que no sepa ingles, simplemente no se me ocurrio :| que se referia a eso. Lo de mi aplicacion era para que no me dijeran que mi aplicacion estaba por el 3000, el 8080 o algo asi, y especificar que lo que me interesaba era el mensaje. thanks